# Android: Cannot resolve symbol setDuration and Toast.LENGTH_LONG

Tags: java, android, text, toast, duration

I am having a problem when setting the duration and text to my toast. I have toasts in 3 of my activities and for some reason it's only happening in 1 of them. I have also tried rebuilding and cleaning the project and that didn't work. 
Here is the code:

```
public class EconFragment extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText userInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInputText);
String userInput = userInputText.getText().toString();

final Toast firstToast = new Toast(this);
final Toast secondToast = new Toast(this);

firstToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
firstToast.setText("Correct");
secondToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
secondToast.setText("Incorrect");

private TextView definitionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definitonTextView);
String definitionText = definitionTextView.getText().toString();

int value = (int )(Math.random() * 3 );
}
```

Comment: `final Toast firstToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`

Comment: Cheers NSimon this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I typically use. It's a little more concise than what you are using.

Toast.makeText(this, "INSERT TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Another user suggested this and it worked. Thanks for this. What I'm trying to figure out is how the above code I used worked in other activities of the same project but not in this one.

Comment: Yea man, that's kinda odd. The more concise you can make your code, the more likely it is going to work. Mind accepting my answer? Thanks